# Range based for-loop for priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, priority-queue

Defining my priority_queue like this,

```
priority_queue<int> parts(start, start+N, less<int>());
```

the following code won't compile

```
for(int t : parts){
    ...
}
```

Which leads me to question:

**In C++11, are range based for loops allowed for** `std::priority_queue`?

In general, which structures are allowed to be iterated trough using a range based for-loop?

I know I can do pretty much the same thing like this:

```
while(!parts.empty()){
    cout << "Next element: " << parts.top() << endl;
    parts.pop();
}
```

Is it possible to iterate trough the queue nevertheless?

Comment: It isn't the same thing, though. The for loop would iterate over the queue and leave it intact (which is generally not what priority queues are for), but the while loop would empty it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4484767/335858

Comment: @FredLarson +1 for "which is generally not what priority queues are for"; this answers exactly my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `std::priority_queue` does not support the range-based for loop.

The range-based for loop works on arrays and on classes that have `begin()` and `end()` member functions. This includes all *containers* in the C++ standard library as well as `std::string` (and its `basic_string` cousins) but not stacks, queues, or priority queues which are *container adaptors* and do not expose iterators.

Comment: @pentix Not portably, no. Might I suggest the use of `std::set`? It's not a drop-in replacement, of course, but can do everything a priority queue can with the same asymptotic complexity (constant factor tends to be worse though)

Comment: I'll have an eye on `std::set`. I just noticed I could write `parts` as a `std::vector<int>`, `std::sort` it using `std::less<int>`. But this seems be a lot of computation for something that `std::set` seems better for. Thanks ;)

Comment: @pentix: If you want the behavior and performance of a `std::priority_queue`, and the ability to iterate, you can use a vector along with the heap operations, [`make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap). In fact, that is exactly how `std::priority_queue` is implemented.