# Priority Queues in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, priority-queue

Is there a way to iterate over a priority queue in c++ ? My understanding is that they are more or less immutable and the only manipulation of the container is to the top element. I would like to be able to print out the contents of a priority queue but am unsure of how to even approach the problem.

Comment: A quick and dirty way is to copy and dequeue, I suppose.

Comment: Not sure if anything new in C++ has changed the [advice in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484767/how-to-iterate-over-a-priority-queue).

Comment: Are you asking about std::priority_queue?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth  yes

Comment: @Keith Then no, not without copying or modifying the queue. I've always thought that queues and stacks should give read-access to the underlying container, but they don't.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Actually `std::priority_queue` does give access to the underlying container through inheritance, even though it's kindly discouraged.

Comment: @sky Oh, I forgot that it was protected :-(  It shouldn't be, IMHO.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've just found that, don't worry. That's why I like to try to answer on SO: I learn a lot!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the input. That gives me a direction to work in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying container is a `protected` data member named `c` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for further details). Therefore you can always inherit from a `std::priority_queue` and *export* a couple of iterators over that container (if available).
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>

struct MyPriorityQueue: std::priority_queue<int> {
    auto begin() const { return c.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return c.end(); }
};

int main() {
    MyPriorityQueue pq;
    pq.push(0);
    pq.push(1);
    for(auto &v: pq) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note: inheriting from data structures in the `std::` namespace is usually discouraged.
That being said, it works at least.

---

The code above works in C++14.
Below a slightly modified version that works also in C++11 as requested in the comments:

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>

struct MyPriorityQueue: std::priority_queue<int> {
    decltype(c.begin()) begin() const { return c.begin(); }
    decltype(c.end()) end() const { return c.end(); }
};

int main() {
    MyPriorityQueue pq;
    pq.push(0);
    pq.push(1);
    for(auto &v: pq) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: auto begin() gives error C3551: expected a trailing return type. At least when compiling with VS2013.

Comment: @Laszlo It's C++14. Put there the right type or a `decltype` to have it working in C++11. I'm updating the answer anyway.

Comment: `error: could not convert ‘((const MyPriorityQueue*)this)->MyPriorityQueue::<anonymous>.std::priority_queue<int>::c.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin<int, std::allocator<int> >()’ from ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}’ to ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >}’
     decltype(c.begin()) begin() const { return c.begin(); }`

Answer (score 3):

Based on @skypjack's answer, here is a templated version:

```
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>

template<class T, class C = vector<T>, class P = less<typename C::value_type> >
struct MyPriorityQueue :
   std::priority_queue<T,C,P> {
   typename C::iterator begin() { return std::priority_queue<T, C, P>::c.begin(); }
   typename C::iterator end() { return std::priority_queue<T, C, P>::c.end(); }
};

int main() {
   MyPriorityQueue<int> pq;
   pq.push(0);
   pq.push(1);
   for (auto &v : pq) {
      std::cout << v << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Unable to use it with `typedef`, 
For example:
`typedef MyPriorityQueue<Obj, vector<Obj>, Cmp> customq_type;`

`customq_type customq(param);`

Gets the following: `error: no matching constructor for initialization of customq_type`.

Please help.

Comment: This is because the constructors were not inherited. `using priority_queue<T,C,P>::priority_queue`, we should be able to inherit the constructors.