# How to make function argument container independent

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I'm writing a utility function which will take a vector of elements (could be string, int, double, char) and concatenate into a single string and return it. It looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convert2Str(std::vector<T> const& vec) 
{
   std::ostringstream sStream; 
   for (size_t k=0; k<vec.size(); ++k) {
      sStream << vec[k] << " "; 
   }
   return sStream.str(); 
}
```

I would like to make this function more generic:

- First use iterators instead of using indices for the `vector<T>`. I tried this 
  `std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = vec.begin()` before the loop and the compiler gave me an error: 
  : error: expected `;` before it
  When I change the above defintions to `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = vec.begin()` the error goes away. So, it looks like I'm not following correct syntax, please let me know what it is
- Second is to make the function more generic by making the first argument container independent. Given any container (`vector`, `list`, `queue`, `deque`, etc.) I want to do the same thing as above. I tried searching for this in stackoverflow and did not find satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1, as you said, use iterators:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convert2Str(std::vector<T> const& vec) 
{
   typedef std::vector<T> container;
   std::ostringstream sStream; 
   for (typename container::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
      sStream << *it << " "; 
   }
   return sStream.str(); 
}
```

Step 2, make the template argument the container type instead of the element type (you can get the element type back with `value_type`:

```
template<typename container>
std::string convert2Str(container const& vec)
{
   typedef container::value_type T; // if needed
   std::ostringstream sStream; 
   for (typename container::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
      sStream << *it << " "; 
   }
   return sStream.str(); 
}
```

In C++0x, this gets even simpler (and `typename` is not needed):

```
template<typename container>
std::string convert2Str(container const& vec)
{
   using std::begin;
   using std::end;
   std::ostringstream sStream;
   for (auto it = begin(vec); it != end(vec); ++it) {
      typedef decltype(*it) T; // if needed
      sStream << *it << " "; 
   }
   return sStream.str(); 
}
```

Among other advantages, `std::begin` and `std::end` work for raw arrays.

Comment: what's the difference between his point 1 and yours. using std::vector<T>::const_iterator doesnt work, but type deffing it does? I am bewildered. HIs solution is just missing a typename in front of the iterator declaration. (As the compiler states) But why? It feels like, a missing struct in c in front of a non typedeffed type.

Comment: @Ronny: It's the `typename` keyword that's needed there.  The typedef is just used to ease the transition to generic container (both `T` and `container` are still defined, but I switch which one is the template argument).

Comment: I guess the line "typedef container::value_type T; // if needed" is what tells the compiler that container is a vector, list, etc. and ensures that convert2Str cannot be called with a simple data type such as int or double. So, why is this statement marked "if needed"..Thanks for prompt answers.

Comment: @srikrish: That line only gets you back the `T` type which existed in your original code.  This function didn't use `T` anywhere, but I wanted to show you how to access it just in case.  Even without this line, if you tried to pass in something that wasn't a container, the compiler would complain about the calls to `begin` and `end`.

Comment: So if T is a user defined type (my own class), can I do something like this sStream << T.getValue() << " "; ??

Comment: @srikrish: No, you can't use `.` after a type.  But you might want to declare a local variable of type `T`, maybe something like `T sum = *it + 5;`.

Answer (score 6):

Following STL practice, I would recommend using two iterators for input parameters, instead of a container (for obvious reason of being able to work with only a part of a container, and generally with any sequence defined by iterators):

```
template<typename InputIterator>
std::string convert2Str(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    std::ostringstream sStream;
    for (InputIterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
       sStream << *it << " ";
    }
    return sStream.str();
}
```

In case you need the type of contained objects, use

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type T;
```

ADDED:
You then can use the function as follows:

```
std::vector<int> int_vec;
std::list<float> f_list;
std::deque<std::string> str_deq;

     // put something into the containers here

std::cout<< convert2Str(int_vec.begin(), int_vec.end()) <<std::endl;
std::cout<< convert2Str(f_list.begin(), f_list.end()) <<std::endl;
std::cout<< convert2Str(str_deq.begin(), str_deq.end()) <<std::endl;
```

Note that you cannot iterate over std::queue; but if you really need it, the standard guarantees enough support for a do-it-yourself solution. See more info here: [std::queue iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/stl-queue-iteration).

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest if you templatize on the container type only; the value type is stored in all standard, Boost and Qt containers as the `typedef` member `value_type`. `std::copy` and `ostream_iterator` allow you to skip the lengthy iterator declarations.

```
template <typename Container>
std::string convert2Str(Container const &cont)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    std::copy(cont.begin(), cont.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(s, " "));
    return s.str();
}
```

The `typename` is necessary to avoid ambiguity. Recent versions of GCC will warn you when you omit this keyword.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't actually teach srikrish how to write a generic function of his own, which is also a useful skill.  And `ostream_iterator<decltype(*cont.begin())>` will be better with C++0x.

Comment: @Ben: `decltype` is confusing; it seems like you're running/evaluating an expression, while really you aren't. Any STL-compliant container will have `value_type` (the standard containers do, the Boost containers do and even those in Qt).

Comment: @larsman: Sorry, it really should be `ostream_iterator<decltype(*begin(cont))>`.  Raw arrays don't have `value_type`, but they do work with `std::begin` and `std::end`.  And it definitely should be `using std::copy; copy(...);` to let Koenig lookup do its thing.  Remember that function templates can't be partially specialized, and defining new overloads in `namespace std` is forbidden, the only way to provide an optimized version of `copy` for a container is using ADL.

Comment: * Is this code portable to platforms such as solaris? I recently used std::count in my code and sun compiler in solaris complained about this. Can you explain what does this statement "std::ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(s, " ")" do? thanks

Comment: @srikrish: it works on any standard-conforming C++ compiler, but I don't know if the Sun compiler is conforming. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ostream_iterator/.

Answer (score 2):

Use this. You need the `typename` part in order to tell the compiler that it should consider `T::const_iterator` a type while parsing, it can't really know that this is true until you actually call the function passing some `T` that has a `const_iterator` member type.

```
template<typename T>
std::string convert2Str(T const& cont) 
{
    std::ostringstream sStream; 
    for (typename T::const_iterator it = cont.begin(); it != cont.end(); ++it) {
        sStream << *it << " "; 
    }
    return sStream.str(); 
}
```

Comment: Good point on `typename`.  Just one more reason to switch to C++0x asap.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convert2Str(T const& container) 
{
   std::ostringstream sStream; 
   for (typename T::const_iterator i= container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i) {
      sStream << *i << " "; 
   }
   return sStream.str(); 
}
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/9pUVV