# Convert a byte array to encoded string

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know how to convert a byte array to string given an encoded scheme e.g

```
string Convert2Str(byte* b, UTF32);
string Convert2Str(byte* b, UTF7);
etc
```

Comment: There is no `string` type in  C.  Suggest removing C tag.

Comment: The only reference in C++ I found was `SysTestAssert.convert2str()` taking only one argument. You could try this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451305/how-to-make-function-argument-container-independent

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: that is a struct I made myself that works like string in c++

Comment: @JoachimPileborg will it work in windows too. my program needs to work only in windows. I am so neveous

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard c++ way to do so.

Some 3rd party libraries are available to convert encodings (e.g. [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)).

---

<sub>**Note:** `byte` isn't a standard c++ type either. You probably meant `uint8_t`.</sub>

Comment: thanks I need utf7, 8,16,32, all but your utf8-cpp only has utf8 which is not enough.

Comment: yes, I define it as a uint8_t only for easier to understand I call it byte

Comment: @MolitaBolida Then research for other 3rd party libraries, that meet your requirements (I'm pretty sure there are some available). Asking for particular ones is off-topic here anyways.