# Creating an Unchangable Queue

Tags: c++, function, queue

I have a question.

I created a random queue called `queue<char> random;` and pushed random values into it.
I then passed the queue to a function called `display_queue` and displayed the queue by popping each element out of the queue. However now none of the elements remain in the queue.

Question:
Is there a way so that after I display the elements in the queue using the function, it does not change the queue that was passed to it?

By the way I am using the STL queue.

Comment: I presume you're passing your queue to `display_queue` by reference.  Don't do that if what you really want is a copy.  :P

Comment: The short answer would be: don't use a queue. You could use (for one example) a `std::deque` instead. It supports all the queue operations, but also supports non-destructive iteration.

Comment: The purpose of the queue is to put items in at one end and pull them out at the other end. Don't use a queue.

Comment: I need to use a queue for the project, and I was hoping there was a way to do it without using a copy. Like maybe using `Const` somehow?

Comment: use const reference to avoid copy, and use queue::iterator instead of pop to display so that you would not change the queue passed in

Comment: If you *have* to use a queue here, and you *have* to iterate via pop, then a copy is what you want.  Then you can modify the copy to your heart's content without breaking the original.  `const` would keep you from changing anything, which would keep you from getting the next item.

Comment: @yangguang1029: Do queues have iterators?

Comment: Ok so I take it that there is no way other than making a copy then?

Comment: Sure there is.  Use the right container for the job.  :P  But if you *need* a std::queue, then copy it.  Not sure why you're so scared of copies, though -- codewise, it's just deleting a `&`.

Comment: yeah definetly need to use a queue, the project is done, I ended up using a copy, but was just curious if I could do it a different way.

Comment: This questoin feels like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/stl-queue-iteration.