# get unsigned int from array of vector

Tags: c++

is a better way to implement this code ?

```
int getBlockVector(vector<unsigned char>& vect, const int pos, const int length)
  {
    int destinyInt = 0;
    switch (length) {
      case 1 : destinyInt = (0x00 << 24)              | (0x00 << 16)              | (0x00 << 8)             | vecct.at(pos);  break;
      case 2 : destinyInt = (0x00 << 24)              | (0x00 << 16)              | (vect.at(pos + 1) << 8)  | vect.at(pos);  break;
      case 3 : destinyInt = (0x00 << 24)              | (vect.at(pos + 2) << 16)   | (vect.at(pos + 1) << 8)  | vect.at(pos);  break;
      case 4 : destinyInt = (vect.at(pos + 3) << 24)   | (vect.at(pos + 2) << 16)   | (vect.at(pos + 1) << 8)  | vect.at(pos);  break;
      default : destinyInt = -1;
return destinyInt;}
```

considering the ugly default value. 
How implement this function with iterators and template for vector, deque, queue, etc.

Note: the bounds are checked before and static_cast is not a desirable option.

Comment: Is it really necessary to bitwise-OR with `0`s?

Comment: @LogicStuff He is paid for the number of typed symbols in the program.:)

Comment: @logicStuff not really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to return an unsigned int, so you'll never get an overflow in case length==4. Also, `vect[]` is shorter than `vect.at()`. Finally, you can replace the switch statement by a loop:

```
unsigned int getBlockVector2(vector<unsigned char>& vect, const int pos, const int length)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < length; ++k)
        result |= vect[k + pos] << (8 * k);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `vector` and `deque` have an `at()` function, so you can use those two containers with your existing function almost as-is, just declare it as a template:

```
template <typename CONTAINER_T>
int getBlockVector(CONTAINER_T& vect, const int pos, const int length) {
    int destinyInt = 0;
    switch (length) {
        case 1 : destinyInt = (0x00 << 24)              | (0x00 << 16)              | (0x00 << 8)             | vect.at(pos);  break;
    /*etc...*/
}
```

A regular `queue` doesn't support random access or iterators, so you can't really make this function work with a `queue`.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/stl-queue-iteration) for workarounds and a more thorough explanation as to why.

You can also initialize `destinyInt` to -1 when you declare it, so you don't need the `default:` line in the switch statement, i.e. `int destinyInt = -1`