# How to convert std::queue to std::vector

Tags: c++, queue, std, stdvector

I need to make use of a queue of doubles because of the good properties it has as an ordered container. I want to pass this queue to a class constructor that accepts vectors. If I do that directly I get the following error:

> candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
>   'std::queue' to 'std::vector &' for 2nd argument

How to cast a queue to a vector?

Comment: Manually create a vector from the queue values?

Comment: Do you need to `queue` to be unmodified?

Comment: How was your `std::queue` declared? The second template parameter can be used to define the underlying container: if you can modify the declaration, choose `std::vector` as container for your queue and you will be able to make some memcpy

Comment: Vector's range constructor is your friend

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct container to model both queue_like behaviour and vector-like behaviour is a `std::deque`.

This has the advantages of:

1. constant-time insertion and deletion at either end of the deque
2. ability to iterate elements without destroying the deque

`std::deque` supports the `begin()` and `end()` methods which means you can construct a vector (with compatible value-type) directly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

class AcceptsVectors
{
public:
  AcceptsVectors(std::vector<double> arg);
};

int main()
{
    std::deque<double> myqueue;

    auto av = AcceptsVectors({myqueue.begin(), myqueue.end()});
}
```

A non-mutating conversion of a `queue` to a `vector` is not possible.

Comment: I think I could do it.  Derive from queue in a hack.  The hack constructs from a queue, but instead of taking the data it creates a vector from the c.  Then it has an operator vector.  Then hide the hack in a helper function.  The source queue remains mutated.

Comment: @Yakk true, but there is no way to do this without suffering either an extra copy of the container or a mutation (move-from)

Comment: The same is true of `deque` tho, which your last sentence doesn't imply.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's any direct way available.
Hence this can be achieved by adding elements one by one to the vector.

```
std::vector<int> v;
while (!q.empty())
{
    v.push_back(q.front());
    q.pop();
}
```

Note that the queue will be empty after this.

As suggested by @David in the comment, it'd be good to avoid copying the queue elements (helpful especially when the contained objects are big). Use `emplace_back()` with `std::move()` to achieve the same:

```
v.emplace_back(std::move(q.front()));
```

Comment: you probably want to **move** the objects returned from `q.front()` rather than copy them: `v.emplace_back(std::move(q.front()));`. non the less, you got my upvote because this is the only answer which actually practical

Answer (score 8):

`std::vector` has a [constructor taking a pair of iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), so if you would be able to iterate over the queue, you would be set.

Borrowing from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/stdqueue-iteration), you can indeed do this by subclassing `std::queue`:

```
template<typename T, typename Container=std::deque<T> >
class iterable_queue : public std::queue<T,Container>
{
public:
    typedef typename Container::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const { return this->c.begin(); }                                                                               
    const_iterator end() const { return this->c.end(); }
};
```

(Note we're allowing only `const` iteration; for the purpose in the question, we don't need iterators allowing modifying elements.)

With this, it's easy to construct a `vector`:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Container=std::deque<T> >
class iterable_queue : public std::queue<T,Container>
{
public:
    typedef typename Container::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const { return this->c.begin(); }                                                                               
    const_iterator end() const { return this->c.end(); }
};

int main() {
    iterable_queue<int> int_queue;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        int_queue.push(i);

    vector<int> v(int_queue.begin(), int_queue.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Max You could also inherit privately or compose, but then you would have to expose all the underlying interface (e.g., with `using`). It depends on the context.

Comment: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 3):

This is just **an approach to avoid copying** from `std::queue` to `std::vector`. I leave it up to you, if to use it or not.

### Premises

`std::queue` is a container adaptor. The internal `container` by default is `std::deque`, however you can set it to `std::vector` as well. The member variable which holds this container is marked as `protected` luckily. Hence you can hack it by subclassing the `queue`.

### Solution (!)

```
template<typename T>
struct my_queue : std::queue<T, std::vector<T>>
{
  using std::queue<T, std::vector<T>>::queue;
  // in G++, the variable name is `c`, but it may or may not differ
  std::vector<T>& to_vector () { return this->c; }
};
```

That's it!!

### Usage

```
my_queue<int> q;
q.push(1);
q.push(2);
std::vector<int>& v = q.to_vector();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uUHSN9).

Comment: FWIW it is defined as `Container c;` in the standard so I would assume all conforming implementations use `c`.

Comment: Vector based queues would be horribly slow.

Comment: could you provide some more detail on what actually is happening in the `return->c` part ? not really sure I understand it

Comment: @serup `my_queue` makes `std::vector` as the underlying container. The variable inside `std::queue` which holds this container is named as `c`. It must be true for all conforming compilers. Now within the `std::queue` since you have the `std::vector` readily available in form of `protected: c`, we don't have to convert this `std::queue` to `std::vector` explicitly using loop iteration. Rather we can simply pass on the `c` when needed. It has to be `this->c` because `c` belongs to base class with dependent type.

Comment: and dependent type means that the this pointer takes type of base class which is T ?