# convert deque or LIFO container to std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have the following use case:

- `containerTypeX` object to which I insert many elements at the front
- After the `containerTypeX` object has everything inserted, the `containerXType` object needs to be converted to a `std::vector`

For `containerTypeX` I chose `std::deque` over `std::vector`, because as far as I know inserting at the begin of a `std::vector` is not efficient.
But now I have to convert the `std::deque` to a `std::vector` and do not want to move every single element from the queue to the vector separately like

```
v.emplace_back(std::move(q.front()));
```

1) Is there a way to directly convert my queue to a vector that I am missing?

2) Should I use a LIFO container like `std::stack` instead of `std::deque` as I am only inserting one one side? But this will leave me the problem that in addition the element ordering needs to be reversed when converted to the `std::vector`...

Related Question: [How to convert std::queue to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699268/how-to-convert-stdqueue-to-stdvector)

Comment: why do you have to insert at the front? Cant you simply insert at the back and pretend that the container is reversed?

Comment: @user463035818 Additionally, you can use `std::reverse` to reverse the order of elements in the `vector`. This should be fast if swapping of elements is efficient.

Comment: The inserting is related to a graph path exploration algorithm. Once I find the last element in the path I trace back and insert previous nodes at the front to get the whole path in right order.

Comment: @DanielLangr as I understand OP, they only want "containerTypeX" to fill it efficiently and then do nothing else than transform that to a vector, so actually it shouldnt matter at all in what order the elements are

Comment: It's almost like this use was planned when `std::vector::rbegin()` and `std::vector::rend()` were created

Comment: @MartinM just change the word "front" to "back" and "previous" to "next" and search in reverse direction and the algorithm will be equivalent, but be fast when using a vector.

Comment: @user463035818 It depends on the (not mentioned) usage of the resulting vector. If it's, e.g., passed as an argument to some library function that requires particular ordering...

Comment: @DanielLangr if the container choice is up to the user of the library, then the library presumably uses iterators. If the library supports iterators, then you can use reverse iterators to solve that problem.

Comment: @DanielLangr if the library was nicely designed it takes iterators :P, anyhow I guess we agree that more information is needed to give a decisive answer

Comment: @user463035818 Agree, we don't know the details. For instance HDF5 or MPI library would need to access underlying buffer of the `vector`, they don't work with iterators at all.

Comment: @MartinM For moving elements from any container to `std::vector` you can use `std::move` algorithm (from `<algorithm>` header) together with `std::back_inserter`. Don't forget to `reserve` vector memory in advance.

Comment: can you show some example code that demonstrates your scenario? Currently it isnt clear why simply using a `std::vector` is not sufficient

Answer (score 2):

> I chose `std::deque` over `std::vector`, because as far as I know inserting at the begin of a `std::vector` is not efficient

Correct.

> 1) Is there a way to directly convert my queue to a vector that I am missing?

What about moving element from old container to new `std::vector` using the `std::vector` constructor that accept a begin/end couple of iterators and the `std::make_move_iterator` adapter?

I mean

```
std::vector<containedType> v(std::make_move_iterator(q.begin()),
                             std::make_move_iterator(q.end()));
```

where `q` is the `std::deque` ?

> 2) Should I use a LIFO container like `std::stack` instead of `std::deque` as I am only inserting one one side? But this will leave me the problem that in addition the element ordering needs to be reversed when converted to the `std::vector`...

You can make the same using reverse iterators

```
std::vector<containedType> v(std::make_move_iterator(s.rbegin()),
                             std::make_move_iterator(s.rend()));
```

where `s` is a LIFO container.

But, as suggested in comments, are you sure you need this conversion? If you use a `std::vector` as LIFO container (so adding element at the end), what about using it reversed with reverse operators?

Answer (score 1):

```
v.reserve(q.size());
std::move(std::begin(q), std::end(q), std::back_inserter(v));
q.clear();
q.shrink_to_fit();
```

However, as noted in comments, inserting at the end of `v` directly and reversing the order of elements (if it is really required) by

```
std::reverse(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

would be likely more efficient.

Comment: Even simpler if they can just create a new vector: `vector(begin(q), end(q))`.

Comment: @user2079303 that copies instead of moving. For the correct version of that, see max66's answer.