# how to check if queue is sorted using stl

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, queue

i would like your help with this question I have, I need to write a C++ function that inputs a queue as parameter and checks whether the contents in the queue are in sorted order (such that the front element is smallest). A `BOOLEAN` value should be returned accordingly. Assuming that there is no duplicated element in the queue.
I am trying to get my head around the concept of sorting, so any help would be appreciated, here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std; 

bool is_Sorted(queue<int> q) {
    int my_front = q.front();
    int my_back = q.back();
    if (my_front==my_back) {
        return true;
    }
    if (my_front+1>my_front) {
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    queue <int> q;
    q.push(3);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(5);
    q.push(6);
    q.push(7);
    is_Sorted(q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Also, why are you only checking the front and back?  You need to make sure every element is in order.

Comment: i tried the code again to check the error so i can write it , it didn't give me any errors , if i wanted to to make a loop so i can go through every element should it be something like this?
for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){}

Comment: You need to check all the elements of the list. Also in the current version, your functions never return `false`. You can go through the list and compare each element with the next one.

Comment: to compare each element with the next one , i should do something like this?:
for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++){
if(my_front+1>my_front){return true;}
else{return false;}
} ??

Comment: Why are you using a queue and not a list ? If you want to iterate on a queue, you can do it as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259099/stdqueue-iteration (the second or third (simpler) answer)

Comment: If you want to get your head around sorting, [start with this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). And no, that for loop in your prior comment is incorrect. It just repeatedly checks the value at front, plus one, against itself without the addition, which will *always* be true. You need to check each element against its successive neighbor in the queue. Learn all the things you can do with a [queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), assuming you're pinned to that data structure for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Because a `queue` doesn't provide iterators you can't use: [`is_sorted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted)

Thus comparison would require copying the `queue` or sequentially `pop`'ing and comparing elements of the `queue`, then `push`'ing them back onto the `queue`. I've chosen to simply copy the `queue` for this example:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_sorted(queue<T> q) {
    if(!empty(q)) {
        for(T i = q.front(); size(q) > 1U; i = q.front()) {
            q.pop();

            if(i > q.front()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This example clearly incurs the cost of copying the `queue` which is clearly undesirable. This cost is incurred because *a `queue` is the wrong tool for the job*. Consider [`priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) or just a [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: `std::queue` doesn't provide iterators to the underlying container.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ugh, how could I forget that, thank you.